# How to resolve warnings in angular-cli

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I am publishing an application with angular-cli to be able to host it on a web server. However, I am getting warnings after the package is generated.

`WARNING in Empty property 'top' at 38528:2. Ignoring.`

See details below:

```
ng build --prod --aot
Date: 2018-04-14T16:43:39.496Z
Hash: 2f4b4864e5fc06f19a78
Time: 29637ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.6a3664adfa303ed2dcb2.bundle.js (scripts) 1.58 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} 0.09154b285423265e2524.chunk.js (common) 378 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1.1f5e8eaa29da0635c303.chunk.js () 4.01 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2.8ad14273acdb738cda55.chunk.js () 96.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} main.a64634c8f4ce92fcfb5a.bundle.js (main) 779 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} polyfills.a5214ab831fec809b225.bundle.js (polyfills) 59.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} styles.57c1b3dde10b6adf85c2.bundle.css (styles) 1.48 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {6} inline.a1e76fba20a162a90f22.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]


WARNING in Empty property 'top' at 38528:2. Ignoring.
```

Comment: Have you looked for the term 'top' in your code to see if there is something odd going on? Maybe you have a variable that is never used, or something like that.

Comment: I've been searching a lot. It's a ready made template that is giving me such warning. Hundreds of files and no luck.